Using PDFBox is there anyway to tag and image to be identified and replaced later
I am using 3.0.2 apache.pdfbox.
I am receiving PDFs from one of our internal systems. In the PDFs, some of the images are just place holders that my system is to replace with the real image.
I have got pdfbox extracting all the images and writing them to the local system
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
           pages.add(document.getPage(i));

           PDPage page = document.getPage(i);

           PDResources resources = page.getResources();
           int x=0;
           for (COSName xObjectName : resources.getXObjectNames()) {
               PDXObject xObject = resources.getXObject(xObjectName);
               if (xObject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                   File file = new File(i +"_"+x + ".png");
                   ImageIO.write(((PDImageXObject)xObject).getImage(), "png", file);
                   x++;
               }
           }
         }

but there does not seem to be any identifying tag or image name retained in the PDXObject
I can not guarantee the image size or index...
Has anyone solved this issue or have any ideas?
